# Create a collection of interfaces with generic types

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of ISnapshot<...> instances. Some of them have an object type for the generic, some have a primitive type and some have an enum type.

```
enum myEnum 
{
}

class myClass
{
  ISnapshot<int> primitiveSnapshot;
  ISnapshot<myClass> objectSnapshot;
  ISnapshot<myEnum> enumSnapshot;
}
```

With this as an example, I want to add all of those into a Collection like this:

```
ICollection<ISnapshot<???>> snapshots = 
  new Collection<ISnapshot<???>> {primitiveSnapshot, objectSnapshot, enumSnapshot};
```

I may not use ICollection<object> because I will lose the fact, that the contents of that Collection are ISnapshot instances.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `ISnapshot`?

Comment: You can make `ISnapshot<T>` derive from a non-generic `ISnapshot` interface, even if it's just empty as a marker. Note that no matter how you slice it, there'll be no (compile time) type-safe way to access whatever's in the snapshot.

Comment: we need to know why you want them all in 1 collection? and how you are going to use the items (what will you try to access) when you will e.g iterate through this collection? because this strongly determines whether the suggestion by Jeroen is applicable for you, or whether we should suggest something else to you. This sounds like a typical X/Y Problem

Comment: The ISnapshot is "public interface ISnapshot<out TData>" and i cannot change its signature since it's 3rd party. The ISnapshot declares a function called "hasError". I want to put all of those snapshots in a single Collection to be able to use a foreach to check, whether any of the snapshots reports an error.

Comment: I don't think this can be solved through generics. Normally the `out` modifier provides some possibility but sadly covariance (and contravariance) only works on reference types (my assumption would be due to boxing). You can however solve this problem with reflection, however that would leave you without type safety on your collection.

Comment: If you can't change the signature the only common type you could make a collection out of is `object`. You can simplify type access by making it `dynamic` instead, but that won't change the essential fact that there's no type-safe way to store these things; the C# type system has no higher-order generics.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I thought that would be the case. Thank you.

Comment: @Knoop any hint on that solution with Reflection? Might need to use it.

Comment: You can look over the objects, get their type and then see if they implement `ISnapshot<>` if they do you can find the property/method whatever called `hasError` and call it/get it's value.